# Capturing video frames as images using AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c

I have a running video in my application. When I press the record button, I need to start recording the running video from the point at which I pressed record button. Then the recorded video has to be saved as another video file.

Can anybody suggest me the best solution to implement this feature. The basic idea is that I need to implement the recording feature similar to Talking Tom application.

Please give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many way to implement this.You can check [This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214052/crashing-on-video-capture-with-avfoundation

Comment: Thanks Saif, I hope the above post is referring to capture the video from the device camera. My requirement is that I have a video file in my resource folder and I need to capture the portion of video from the video file in which I am placed in the resource folder.